# Why do some bamboo flutes use bindings?

Tags: instruments, flute

I have both the Dizi (Chinese traverse bamboo flute) and the Bansuri (Indian traverse Bamboo flute).

The Dizi has plastic bindings:

[image: Dizi]

The Bansuri has thread bindings:

[image: Bansuri]

Why do bamboo flutes like the Dizi and Bansuri use bindings? What is the use of these bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop them cracking.   Or, rather, to stop them opening up when they DO crack.

http://www.clintgoss.com/binding.html